# concept of virtual functions in c++

Tags: c++, virtual-functions

I am trying to understand the concept of virtual function in C++ and I read it online but I am not able to understand why the below program output is 2 instead of 1? Can anyone explain?

```
Class A 
{ 
   int a; 
   public: 
       A() 
       {
          a = 1; 
       } 
       virtual void show() 
       { 
          cout <<a;
       } 
};

Class B: public A 
{ 
   int b; 
   public: 
       B() 
       { 
          b = 2; 
       }
       virtual void show() 
       { 
          cout <<b;
       }
};

int main() 
{ 
   A *pA; 
   B oB; 
   pA = &oB; 
   pA->show(); 
   return 0; 
}
```

Comment: Can you explain why you would expect the result to be "1"?

Comment: why do you think the output should be `1` actually?

Comment: Keep reading your C++ book, which explains this concept fully.

Comment: remove `virtual` keywords and you'll have what you want: 1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you achieve polymorphism with overriding virtual functions and pointers:
in your example you used pA polymorphically so it is a pointer to a base class (A) but you but you assign to it a class B's object which is child of A.
and you you declared Show() as virtual.

this is the main goal of polymorphis; which means we don't know the type of object the base pointer points to until runtime eg in main:

```
int main() 
{ 

   int choice;
   cout << "1: A object   2: B object:\n\n";
   cin >> choice;
   if(1 == choice)
       pA = new A; // result will be 1
   else
       if(2 == choice)
           pA = new B; // result will be 2

    if(pA)
        pA->show();
    delete pA;
    pA = NULL;

//  B* pB = new A; // error: cannot convert from class A* to class B* because C++ is not contravariant 
    B* pB = new B;
    pB->show(); // result: 2

    delete pB;
    pB = NULL;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/virtual)

> Virtual functions are member functions whose behavior can be overridden in derived classes. As opposed to non-virtual functions, the overridden behavior is preserved even if there is no compile-time information about the actual type of the class. **If a derived class is handled using pointer or reference to the base class, a call to an overridden virtual function would invoke the behavior defined in the derived class.** This behavior is suppressed if the function is selected using qualified name lookup (that is, if the function's name appears to the right of the scope resolution operator ::)

Since, you are overriding `show()` in class `B`, `pA->show()` will call `show()` in class `B`.
Hope this helps